# How to catch ProcessFailedException in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, try-catch

I'm currently **scraping** my site with Puphpeteer.

Something I do is click on ocurrances of certain links. Sometimes, by the time I click on the link it doesn't exist anymore and it throws the following exception:

```
Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException
```

I simply want to ignores those exceptions and continue with the loop.

I tried the below but it doesn't catch it:

```
foreach ($linkHandlers as $link){
    try {
        $link->click();                 
    } catch (Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException $e) {
        
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException: The command "node C:\xampp\htdocs\xxxx\node_modules\@nesk\rialto\src\node-process\serve.js C:\xampp\htdocs\xxxxx\vendor\nesk\puphpeteer\src\PuppeteerConnectionDelegate.js "{""idle_timeout"":60,""log_node_console"":false,""log_browser_console"":false}"" failed.

Exit Code: 1(General error)
```

Comment: Is it a 500 error? In any case, try "\" before symfony. as in: `\Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException $e` OR, if that doesnt work, why not catch all exceptions (`\Exception $e`) there and see if the exception is an instance of this ProcessFailedException.

Comment: None of both works - the exception is firing in a vendor's file, for a case it change things:
`C:\xampp\htdocs\xxxx\vendor\nesk\rialto\src\ProcessSupervisor.php(364): Nesk\Rialto\ProcessSupervisor->checkProcessStatus()`

Comment: I also tried `\Throwable`, but no luck

Comment: Ah sad, I dont have any more suggestions. Sorry. Let's hope someone more knowledgeable sees this.